# How to update label from another class c#

Tags: c#

if i put threadtest() in form1.cs it will work correctly but i want to move to another class it will show error. This is screenshot of error

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread thread;
    bool loop = true;
    volatile bool _cancelPending = false;
    Stopwatch regularSW = new Stopwatch();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => threadtest()));
        thread.Start();
    }
    public void threadtest()
    {
        while (loop)
        {
            regularSW.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            regularSW.Stop();
            label1.Text = "Sleep in: " + regularSW.Elapsed + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because `label1` is declared in `Form1`?

Comment: Why not use a Timer for this?....

Answer (score 2):

The Form1 class is the code-behind class of your windows form. The label named label1 is not defined in Class1.

Can you use events?

Define a different parameter that you can update.

```
public event Action<string> onStatusChange;
public void threadtest()
{
    var status = "";
    while (loop)
    {
        regularSW.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        regularSW.Stop();
        if(null != onStatusChange)
        {
             onStatusChange("Sleep in: " + regularSW.Elapsed + Environment.NewLine);
        }            
    }
}
```

In Form1 class:

```
var class1 = new Class1();
class1.onStatusChange += (status) => { label1.Text = status; };
class1.threadtest();
```

Comment: The Form1 class needs to access a Class1 instance.

Comment: ...or use events as I have altered my answer to show

Answer (score -1):

try below code.
In your Form1 class `button1_Click` add the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Class1 class1Object = new Class1();
    thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => class1Object.threadtest(this)));
    thread.Start();
   }
}
```

Now change your class1 `threadtest()` function as below:

```
class Class1
{
     public void threadtest(Form1 form)
     {
    while (loop)
    {
        regularSW.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        regularSW.Stop();
        form.label1.Text = "Sleep in: " + regularSW.Elapsed + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You can't update the UI from a separate thread...use `form.Invoke()`.  Also, you'd have to change the `Modifiers` property for "label1" so it'll be visible outside the Form1 class...